Extracting all values of a spilled range using Office Scripts
I am attempting to extract all of the values that result from a spilled range using Office Scripts, for extraction using Power Automate. The spilled range is the result of a filter operation that places the resulting values in a named range within the spreadsheet. It seems that it should be a simple thing to grab these values, but so far I have achieved either getting only the first value, or an error.
Within my function main() I include:
let varFilteredList = worksheet.getRange("FilteredSpillRange").getValues();

The result is a single-value array, even though there should be two values. Using getValue() also gives me only the first value, but as a single item instead of as an array (unsurprisingly). It seems like this should be simple, but my Google searches have only hit dry holes so far. I'd appreciate help from this list.
Thanks.

Is FilteredSpillRange a named range?

@taller, yes, it is a named range.


Use getSpillingToRange() to get the spilled range

Microsoft documentation:

Excel.Range class

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    let dataRange = worksheet.getRange("A3").getSpillingToRange();
    console.log(dataRange.getAddress());
    let varFilteredList = dataRange.getValues();
    console.log(varFilteredList);
}



After a little more testing, I ran into a complication: sometimes my filter returns several values, sometimes one, sometimes none. If it returns two or more and creates a spill, the code that @taller provided works great. But if it returns one or no values, no spill is produced, and .getValues returns an error.
My solution was to use the .getHasSpill() method on the range to test whether the range returned a multi-value array or a single value. If an array, I then used the code @taller provided, but if a single value then I used the .getValue() method.
There may well be a more elegant way to achieve this, but it seems to work pretty well.
